# Анимация выдвигающего списка. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, анимация

У меня есть программа, в которой есть список, я решил сделать анимацию. И вот не могу сделать анимацию "Выдвигающего списка". Вот код:

```
private void btnMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panelMainSubMenu.Visible = true;
            panelMainSubMenu.Size = new Size(panel1.Size.Height, 0);
        }
int panel_y = 0;
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            panel_y += 1;
            panelMainSubMenu.Size = new Size(panel1.Size.Height, panel_y);
        if (panel_y > 154)
        {
            timer2.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

Проблема: При нажатии на кнопку Height не становится равен 0. И ещё один вопрос, как сделать, чтобы анимация прервалась по нажатию кнопки и Height cтал равен 0.

Comment: посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917918/animations-sliding-fading-controls-on-a-c-sharp-form-winforms)

Comment: покажите, где вы запускаете таймер, обработчик у вас вызывается как надо? [точку останова](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019) ставили?

Comment: Здравствуйте, забыл указать, что таймер запускается по нажатию кнопки. Dock у списка Top

Comment: Покажите код запуска таймера, и про то, вызывается ли обработчик таймера вы не ответили.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я из-за свой невнимательности забыл обнулить `panel_y` в button_click. Обнулив эту переменную всё заработало.